# Run functions when current time is outside user metadata database times

Tags: php, datetime, comparison

I have a somewhat complicated time equation that had been driving me mental!

What I have so far is:

```
$current  = time();    // UTC time
$user_in  = '8:00 am'; // local time
$user_out = '4:00 pm'; // local time
$gmt_off  = '11';      // Australia EST (+1 at the moment)
```

I then have the function that will convert the local time to UTC by subtracting the GMT offset, and output it as `g:i a`

```
function utc( $time ) {
    $time = ( empty($time) ? null : strtotime($time) );
    $gmt  = '60 * 60 * 11'; // there is an actual check for it to be 10 or 11 - and in seconds

    $out = ( $time - $gmt );
    $out = date( 'Y-m-d g:i a', $out );

    return $out;
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to properly configure the conditions to check if the current time is outside the `$user` times

```
$user_in_utc  = utc( $user_in );
$user_out_utc = utc( $user_out );

if( $current < $user_in_utc && $current > $user_out_utc ) {
    // do something
}
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that say current time is 6:00pm local time.

How do I check it is now currently less than `$user_out` when it keeps saying the date is today and not tomorrow?

I intend for these functions to run if the statement being true as a cron task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get your timestamp values, and they will all be in the same timezone and hence directly comparable. Note that your condition should use `||` (or) rather than `&&` (and) to check if the time is outside user hours.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$current  = strtotime('now');
$user_in  = strtotime('8:00 am');
$user_out = strtotime('4:00 pm');
if( $current < $user_in || $current > $user_out ) {
    // do something
}
```